# Is there any way to add value instead of label in a tag selector component with react-select?

Tags: reactjs, tags, react-select

I'm working with react-select to select some tags that I need to go adding in a input as they are selected. Here is my component code

```
import React from 'react';

import Select from 'react-select';
import makeAnimated from 'react-select/animated';


const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();

const options = [
    { value: 'brown', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'red', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'white', label: 'Vanilla' }
  ]

export default function InputTag(props) {

  return (
    <Select
      closeMenuOnSelect={true}
      components={animatedComponents}
      isMulti
      options={options}
      onChange={(value) => props.onChange(value)}
      
    />
  );
}
```

**What I need is: When I select a Label in the dropdown  the value which corresponds will be added, not the label directly.**

e.g: If I choose **Chocolate** label I need to add **brown** value to the  field

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to make user select Chocolate but add Brown as if user selected Brown. It does not sound very user friendly since the user does not actually know what they are selecting. But if you insist on doing this, you can use the component in controlled mode and handle the value yourself.

```
const [value,setValue]  = React.useState()
const onChange = (value) => {
    setValue({value : value.value, label : value.value})
}


return (
    <Select
        closeMenuOnSelect={true}
        components={animatedComponents}
        isMulti
        options={options}
        onChange={(value) => this.onchange(value)}
        value = {value}      
     />
  );
}
```

You can also check the example on the [github](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) for controlled mode.